# Как задать необязательный параметр в пользовательской функции JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как правильно задать необязательный параметр в функции JS?
Пишу как принято в PHP:

```
function process(param, aparam, bparam = false)
{
    // выполняется некоторый код здесь
        if (bparam)
        {
            // выполнить код
        }
}
```

Т.е. `bparam` может быть передан, а может и отсутствовать.
В Mozilla весь код работает, ошибок нет. В Opera, IE не работает, ошибка `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` ссылается на строку `function process(param, aparam, bparam = false)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В *JavaScript* (до *ECMAScript 6*) нельзя задать значение параметра по умолчанию. Но можно параметр просто не передавать при вызове. В этом случае внутри функции он будет равен `undefined`. Поэтому можно сделать так:

```
function process(param, aparam, bparam) {
    if (bparam == undefined) bparam = false;
    // . . .
}
```

А можно немного схитрить:

```js
function f(arg) {
    var tag = document.getElementById("out");
    out.innerHTML = arg ? "true" : "false";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="f();">f()</button>
<br />
<button onclick="f(true);">f(true)</button>
<br />
<button onclick="f(false);">f(false)</button>
<br />
<div id="out"></div>
```

Значения по умолчанию нет, аргумента нет, но при этом всё работает! Почему? Всё дело в том, что при проверке в `if` значение `undefined` будет эквивалентно `false`.

Comment: В моем случае хитрость будет иметь вид: `var $d = d ? true : false;  и проверка  if ($d) {...` или можно без создания переменной сделать?

Comment: @Plush `if (d) { /* ветка для true */ } else { /* ветка для false/undefined */ }`

Answer (score 4):

В [ES6 добавили возможность задавать параметры по умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```
function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a*b;
}

multiply(5); // 5
```

Но так как эта возможность поддерживается не всеми браузерами вы и получаете указанную ошибку.

Можете использовать старый способ задания значения по умолчанию

```
function multiply(a, b) {
  b = typeof b !== 'undefined' ?  b : 1;

  return a*b;
}

multiply(5); // 5
```

Если *undefined* допустимое значение параметра, то так же можно проверить количество переданных параметров с помощью `arguments.length`